# How to embed binary in request/response with cote?

Tags: node.js

I am new to cote.js (http://cote.js.org/), and as much as it is a convenient framework, I found it difficult to embed binary in request/response.

For example if I am making a request:

```
const cote = require('cote');
const requester = new cote.Requester({ name: 'test' });
const request = { type: 'test', binary: toString(binary) };
requester.send(request, (res) => {
  var returnedBinary = new Buffer(res);
  // do something with the returned binary
});
```

Then on the server side I will do:

```
const cote = require('cote');
const responder = new cote.Responder({ name: 'test' });
responder.on('test', (req, cb) => {
  var newBinary = new Buffer(req.binary);
  // do something with the new binary
  cb(toString(newBinary));
});
```

See here I kept converting binary to string and then convert it back. This seems to be counterproductive to me. Is there a way to request and response with binary directly?